# text file created on all terminal servers (unable to find where to disable)

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2019

I have strange problem in Windows Server 2019 environment with 2 domain controllers and 2 terminal servers. On every logon of new user, a text file is created on the user's desktop on both of TS's. I'm really desperate to find by which settings is this file created. I have unlinked all of the DC's group policies, applied new settings by gpupdate /force and it didn't help. I also check local policies on the servers, but there is nothing. I have reviewed all the scripts on the terminal servers, task scheduler, but there is no similar settings.

I have checked the user policies applied on TS with gpresult, but there is no unknown policy which may create the file.

Is there some other possibility how to find out why the file is created? Thanks

Comment: How is the file named, and what does it contain? It looks like some application might be creating it, this doesn't seem to be related to Windows or TS. Never heard of Windows creating a text file on a user's desktop.

Comment: Unless it's "desktop.ini", then it's supposed to be there and it should be hidden.

Comment: Hi Massimo, it's name is x.txt and contains just character b. It's probably some sample file to test the group policy rule or something similar.

Comment: If this is the case, you can use RSOP (or run `gpresult /h` as one of your users) to list all applied GPOs and their settings.

Comment: I already checked the settings with gpresult, as I wrote above, but since I unlinked all the gpo's, there is nothing to apply.

Comment: Then it's not a GPO. You need to check somewhere else.

Comment: Have you the preferences part of the GPO? Who is the owner of the file?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the file you can see the file in the Default user profile (`c:\users\default`), specifically `c:\users\default\desktop` in your case since you mentioned the file is on the desktop.

Take a look at `c:\users\public\desktop` too, because this is the "all users" desktop.

If you can't find the file in the Default profile nor in Public desktop, you should log on as administrator on one of your Session Host, start capturing with [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), while capturing: logon as standard user, wait for the file to appear, go back to your admin session, stop the capture, add a new Filter: *Path Contains x.txt*, thus you'll be able to see which process creates the file.